# Group By com sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-select, group-by

Estou tentando agrupar os dados do meu select , de acordo com o campo C9_CARGA , contudo quando executo esse select ele me retorna sem estar agrupado , acredito que esteja fazendo algo errado .

Como está me retornando :
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
SELECT Cast(Getdate() AS DATE), 
       Ltrim (Rtrim (c9_carga))   AS CARGA, 
       Ltrim (Rtrim (c6_filial))  AS FILIAL, 
       Ltrim (Rtrim (a4_nome))    AS TRANSPORTADORA, 
       Ltrim (Rtrim (dak_caminh)) AS PLACA, 
       Ltrim (Rtrim (da4_nome))   AS MOTORISTA, 
       Ltrim (Rtrim (da4_numcnh)) AS CNH, 
       Ltrim (Rtrim (da4_rg))     AS RG, 
       Ltrim (Rtrim (a1_nome))    AS NOME, 
       Ltrim (Rtrim (c6_num))     AS PEDIDO, 
       Ltrim (Rtrim (c6_produto)) AS PRODUTO, 
       Ltrim (Rtrim (c6_descri))  AS DESCRICAO, 
       Ltrim (Rtrim (c6_um))      AS UN, 
       Ltrim (Rtrim (c9_qtdlib))  AS QUANTIDADE, 
       b1_peso                    AS PESO_BRUTO 
FROM   sc9010 
       LEFT JOIN dak010 
              ON c9_filial = dak_filial 
                 AND c9_carga = dak_cod 
       LEFT JOIN sc6010 
              ON c9_filial = c6_filial 
                 AND c9_pedido = c6_num 
                 AND c6_cli = c9_cliente 
                 AND c6_loja = c9_loja 
                 AND c6_item = c9_item 
                 AND c6_produto = c9_produto 
       LEFT JOIN sb1010 
              ON b1_cod = c6_produto 
       LEFT JOIN sa1010 
              ON a1_cod = c6_cli 
                 AND a1_loja = c6_loja 
       LEFT JOIN da3010 
              ON da3_filial = dak_filial 
                 AND da3_cod = dak_caminh 
       LEFT JOIN da4010 
              ON da3_filial = da4_filial 
                 AND da4_cod = da3_motori 
       LEFT JOIN sa4010 
              ON a4_cod = dak_transp 
                 AND a4_filial = dak_filial 
WHERE  sc9010.d_e_l_e_t_ <> '*' 
       AND sc6010.d_e_l_e_t_ <> '*' 
       AND sc9010.d_e_l_e_t_ <> '*' 
       AND sb1010.d_e_l_e_t_ <> '*' 
       AND sa1010.d_e_l_e_t_ <> '*' 
       AND da3010.d_e_l_e_t_ <> '*' 
       AND da4010.d_e_l_e_t_ <> '*' 
       AND sa4010.d_e_l_e_t_ <> '*' 
       AND c9_carga <> '' 
       AND c9_nfiscal = '' 
GROUP  BY c9_carga, 
          c6_filial, 
          a4_nome, 
          dak_caminh, 
          da4_nome, 
          da4_numcnh, 
          da4_rg, 
          a1_nome, 
          c6_num, 
          c6_produto, 
          c6_descri, 
          c6_um, 
          c9_qtdlib, 
          b1_peso
```

Comment: não quer dizer necessariamente que o campo `C9_CARGA` não esteja sendo agrupado, o grouping inclui todos os campos, qualquer campo no group by pode estar causando isso, como NOME, CNH ou PESO_BRUTO por exemplo. Faça  o select com todos os campos sem group filtrando pelo que aperece repetido ( `where c9_carga=13974 and ....`) e veja quem está causando o problema

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente algum dos campos ai tem espaços vazios. Tenta utilizar o RTRIM e LTRIM também no group by, pode ser isso